# c# make http call to service on premise (behind firewall) using Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I have a REST service on premise behind firewall, etc. The service is not exposed to the internet. I need to connect securely to that service from the internet.

I am wondering if Azure Service Bus can pass a HTTP Request to a service and return the HTTP Response?

Something like in this horible image bellow.

- WCF Service Bus Client Service installed on premise
- Server running in Azure

The server in Azure can issue HTTP request to custom url in premise like: `http://intranet.domain.com` by using Service Bus Relay.

Is this scenario possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hybrid connections which are a feature of Azure BizTalk Services. This lets your Azure Web or Mobile App access any on-premise resource  that uses a static TCP port, such as SQL Server, HTTP Web APIs etc.

You need to install a listener agent on-premise that can connect to the machine that is running the REST service and the communication happens over a secure connection between the on-premise service and the Azure web app.

1. [Hybrid connections overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-overview)
2. [Setting up a hybrid connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-get-started)

Comment: Didn't knew about this. Does it uses same principle as service bus? I mean the service bus creates a TCP connection therefore you don't need to open ports, etc so will just work.

Comment: Yes. This needs outbound TCP connectivity without having to open any ports.

Comment: one more question: is there a way to handle the whole thing dynamically/programmatically?

Comment: there is a REST API to set it up or you can also use powershell
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn232347.aspx